# How Can I Detect micro-service Failure in Istio and Automatic recovery selection

Tags: istio, servicemesh

I'm new in Istio.

My question is how can I detect failures in services that are already running in istio?

and if there is a failure, how to define particular percentage of traffic to a new version of a service?

thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I recommend using  [Kiali](https://kiali.io/). Kiali helps you understand the structure and health of your service mesh by monitoring traffic flow and report.

> Kiali is a management console for an Istio-based service mesh. It provides dashboards, observability, and lets you operate your mesh with robust configuration and validation capabilities. It shows the structure of your service mesh by inferring traffic topology and displays the health of your mesh. Kiali provides detailed metrics, powerful validation, Grafana access, and strong integration for distributed tracing with Jaeger.

Detailed documentation for installing Kiali can be found in the [Installation Guide](https://kiali.io/documentation/latest/installation-guide/).

---

I have created a simple example to demonstrate how useful Kiali is.

First, I created a `db-app` application with two available versions (`v1` and `v2`) and exposed it using single service:

```
# cat db-app.yml 
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  labels:
    app: db-app
  name: db-app
  namespace: default
spec:
  ipFamilies:
  - IPv4
  ports:
  - port: 80
    protocol: TCP
    targetPort: 80
  selector:
    app: db-app
  type: ClusterIP
---
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  labels:
    app: db-app
    version: v1
  name: db-app-v1
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: db-app
      version: v1
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: db-app
        version: v1
    spec:
      containers:
      - image: nginx
        name: nginx
---
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  labels:
    app: db-app
    version: v2
  name: db-app-v2
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: db-app
      version: v2
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
       app: db-app
       version: v2       
    spec:
      containers:
      - image: nginx
        name: nginx


# kubectl apply -f db-app.yml 
service/db-app created
deployment.apps/db-app-v1 created
deployment.apps/db-app-v2 created

# kubectl get pod,svc
NAME                             READY   STATUS    RESTARTS   AGE
pod/db-app-v1-59c8fb999c-bs47s   2/2     Running   0          39s
pod/db-app-v2-56dbf4c8d6-q24vm   2/2     Running   0          39s

NAME                 TYPE        CLUSTER-IP      EXTERNAL-IP   PORT(S)   AGE
service/db-app       ClusterIP   10.102.36.142   <none>        80/TCP    39s
```

Additionally, to illustrate how we can split the traffic, I generated some traffic to the `db-app` application:

```
# kubectl run test-traffic --image=nginx 
pod/test-traffic created
# kubectl exec -it test-traffic -- bash
root@test-traffic:/# for i in $(seq 1 100000); do curl 10.102.36.142; done
...
```

Now in [Kiali UI](https://kiali.io/documentation/latest/tutorial/#03-traffic-shifting) in the `Graph` section we can see traffic flow:
[image]

In the `Services` section, we can easily split traffic between the `v1` and `v2` versions using the Traffic Shifting Wizard:
**NOTE:** Detailed tutorial can be found in the Kiali [Traffic Shifting tutorial](https://kiali.io/documentation/latest/tutorial/#03-traffic-shifting).
[image]

We can also monitor the status of our application. As an example, I broke the `v1` version:

```
# kubectl set image deployment/db-app-v1 nginx=nnnginx
deployment.apps/db-app-v1 image updated
```

In Kiali UI we see errors in the `v1` version:
[image]

I suggest you read the [Kali Official Tutorial](https://kiali.io/documentation/latest/tutorial/) to learn the full capabilities of Kali.